# Tracker.Current.Interaction.Pages in Sitecore is returning only the current page

Tags: experience-analytics, tracking

I know that Tracker.Current.Interaction.Pages should return all the pages user has visited in the current session. Where as in my case it is returning only the current page. Can someone please let me know what could have gone wrong here. Is there any config setting or someplace which could be causing this to behave this way.

Comment: If you look into the the Experience Profile for invidivual visitors, are those showing the visitor with all the different pages they've visited. Or is each visitor just a single page?

Comment: Also, which version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Do you have VisitorIdentification enabled in your layout/view?

Comment: Sounds like your session is finishing after every request. That means it creates a new interactions entry for each request. Can you also check the Analytics mongoDB, Interactions collection. Do page reloads and check this collection. Don't you have somewhere `Session.Abandon()` in your code?

Comment: Check this troubleshooting page which encompasses some of the above suggestions: http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/10/Troubleshooting-Sitecore-8-XP-Analytics.aspx. Then report back. :)